# How to get a unique primary key from a range select in concurrent table reads

Tags: mysql, sql

Morning,

I've got multiple clients trying to get a unique primary key on a table.

A row identified by that PK is considered "valid" only if they match a successful range scan. The range scan is `SELECT id FROM lookup WHERE allowed='Y' and updated<=NOW() LIMIT 1`

```
------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| fullname   | varchar(250)  | NO   | UNI | 0                 |                |
| allowed    | enum('Y','N') | NO   | MUL | N                 |                |
| updated    | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| hits       | smallint(6)   | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |
| stop_allow | enum('Y','N') | NO   | MUL | N                 |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Once that is first select is done, another SELECT is executed in order to retrieve the content.

The problem is that many clients are doing the same thing at the same time (or they do randomly find a way to match each other grrrr...).

So far, I've tried:

1)

```
 start transaction;
 *range scan* LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
 SELECT * from lookup WHERE id=(result of the range scan);
 *perform stuff*
 commit;
```

This is a performance killer. Stuff is locked forever and "Mysql server goes to heaven" after some time.

2)

```
 start transaction;
 *range scan*
 SELECT * from lookup WHERE id=(result of the previous query) FOR UPDATE;
 *perform stuff*
 commit;
```

This fails miserably with autocommit=0, but it is quite fast

3) At this point, I'm starting to think that transactions are the problem

```
 no transaction;
 //get a row that is not being processed
 *range scan* LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_mem_table WHERE **temp_mem_table.id IS NULL**
 $rid = (result of the range scan)

 //check if another client is doing the same thing, if so then stop here
 select 1 from temp_mem_table WHERE id=$rid
 //if there is a result => return null; this is not enough to block stuff going through

 //signal to other client that this ID is being processed
 insert into temp_mem_table(id) values($rid)
 //get the content
 SELECT * from lookup WHERE id=($rid); 
 *perform time intensive operations*
```

Edit: the temp_mem_table is in fact a memory table, that is flushed on in a while. It does look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_mem_table(id int(11), primary key(id)) engine=memory
```

Thought process is: if what's being processed is stored on a memory table accessible to all clients, then they should be able to know what their friends are doing. The check should stop any further processing. But somehow they find a way to go through :(

After a short period of time, it appears that almost 50% of those primary keys were processed at least twice.

I'm going to find a way of doing this, but maybe some of you encountered a similar situation and can help.

thanx

Comment: Temporary tables are only visible to the current client. Each client gets their own, private copy of temporary tables.

Comment: What I meant by tempory is: CREATE table tmp (id int(11), PRIMARY KEY (id)) engine=memory default charset=utf8;

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It sounds like you are using the 'range scan' to acquire an application level 'lock' on an item. If so, then you may need to change the approach and implement separate locking where acquiring a lock is a (sub-)transaction.

Comment: I'm trying to distribute tasks over multiple clients with Mysql. Excuse me but I cannot quite get the "sub transaction" part in your answer.

Comment: I think I would be tempted to add a column (or possibly on another table) a field to say the row is being processed. Possibly a timestamp so you know to ignore the 'lock' after a short while. This can be allocated in a single UPDATE statement doing a join to get the latest element. However I would need more details to know if this were a reasonable solution and to give a real solution.

Comment: I will try to clarify now

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who encountered the famous "How do I select a unlocked row in Mysql?" such as seen here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49763 and a lot of other place. Here is a dirty hack to solve it.

This is done in READ REPEATABLE MODE which should be ACID over 9000 or at least won't break anything (maybe).

The start point is to have some kind of 'range' of rows that needs to be locked for read so other clients won't get it no matter what.

```
 SELECT pk FROM tbl LIMIT 0,10
 SELECT pk FROM tbl where *large range scan*
```

I do create a memory table (because it should be faster) such as:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
`pid` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`tid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `pid` (`pid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `tid` (`tid`)
 ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Pid is a unique identifier of the client. In my case its the actual process id.
Tid is the task id which matches the primary key of that huge table in which we perform some king of range scan.

Then pseudo-code is like this:

```
 SELECT pk from tbl WHERE (range scan) or limit 0,100
 delete from jobs where pid=$my_pid
 foreach of those pk do
 if(insert IGNORE into jobs(pid,tid) values(1234,pk)) break;
 done;
 select pk from jobs where pid=$my_pid
 select * from big_tbl where id=pk
```

Have tested this with 2,10,25,50 and 100 concurrent clients and got 100% unique distribution of tasks across each client.

Now this might not be super complicated, or might not look elegant but I don't give a damn as long as CPU stays cool.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add another column to the table to indicate that the row is being processed, and by whom? Then you could do:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE lookup SET owner=<client id>
    WHERE id=( SELECT id FROM *range scan* ...
        AND owner IS NULL
        AND completed = false
    FOR UPDATE);
COMMIT;

*do stuff*

UPDATE lookup SET owner=NULL, completed=true,... WHERE owner=<client id>;
```

The final `UPDATE` will never cause a conflict as long as every client has its own unique ID, and the initial `SELECT` can be `LIMIT`ed, and with proper indexing ought to be quite fast.

**It is important that the last `UPDATE` keeps the row unselectable by the other clients**. That is, the initial `SELECT` gets those rows where `owner` is `NULL` and `completed` is false; the first `UPDATE` makes them unselectable in that they now have an owner; the final `UPDATE` keeps them unselectable in that they are now completed.

*Note: I hadn't realized this solution had already been proposed in a comment by user Kickstart.*

Comment: Yea I can see your solution working. But i don't understand why you update the owner. In my case the element that changes is the primary key of the main table. The number of rows in the jobs table matches the number or concurrent client (1..100). Using updates though is pretty good. I'm gonna commit first and try to use something similar to your thought.

Comment: To tell the truth, I'm not too comfortable with changing a table's primary keys. Probably just a quirk of mine, that. But if I can do it some other way, that's what I'll usually end up doing.

Comment: I'm testing something similar to this solution atm. I kinda fear huge gap locks on the main table due to the range scan. Kind of the same effect seen in my first test. I'm gonna try it anyway, since I do have growing CPU usage over time. Maybe I really need to go in the READ COMMITTED transaction level. I can't tell now, need more tests.

Comment: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'u' for update in FROM clause. Trying in 2 step ...

Comment: Your solution doesn't work at all. In fact with 5 concurrent client I do get 30 duplicates out of 70 tasks. The problem is coming from the range select that return the very same value to the clients. It seems that they do find a way to finish their job and release (owner=NULL) so fast that other clients just get the very same row. Or it might be that MVCC they have in READ REPEATABLE MODE i'm no mysql expert but it seems that each client get their own copy when they start a transaction so what they see is not what their friends see. In fact i do think they all see the exact same row.

Comment: Unless someone has something better than what I posted. I will need to write a specific daemon to distribute those tasks perfectly accross all clients.

Comment: I've slightly clarified and modified the approach. I'll be running some tests this weekend; the problem intrigues me.

Comment: Okay, I'll be checking later then. I've got to solve a performance issue now. Thanx